# Error in seq.default when working with mixed effects model

Tags: r, model, statistics

I am attempting to run simple_slopes on a mixed effects model. Why am I getting the below error?

> simple_slopes(mixed.lmer)
> Error in seq.default(to = nrow(grid)) : 'to' must be of length 1